# which time zone is used by pandas Series.dt.weekday_name?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, gmt

I have a pandas date time field and I am using Series.dt.weekday_name to get the week day name. The date time field is in GMT. The data corresponds to two different locations India and USA. At 6:52 pm in GMT.. it is 12:22 am tuesday in IST and 1:52 pm in USA CDT. How can I make sure I am getting the correct weekday using this pandas inbuilt method? If not, is there an other way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It uses `datetime` [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html#pandas.Series.dt.date) so it will be based on your computer clock.